# Nuclio - "/bin" is not a valid file

Tags: nuclio

When I try to run Nuclio, I receive the following error:

`nuclio\plugin\fileSystem\reader\FileReaderException "/bin" is not a valid file.`

This is a new installation with a custom application. I moved the application into a folder named "private".

What should I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to the application not receiving a correct config path.

In your `init.hh` file, add an `args` key and provide the application constructor parameters as shown in the below example:

```
<?hh //patial
return HH\Map {
  'sampleApp\\SampleApp' => HH\Map {
    'autoInit' => true,
    'args'=>HH\Vector
    {
        '/',                       //URI Binding
        __DIR__.'/sampleApp/config' //Config Dir
    }
  }
};
```

Without this, the Application plugin will try to search for config but eventually give up giving the resulting error.

We'll make the error more obvious in a future release.